# Jsp and ?: not working as expected

Tags: jsp, el, conditional-operator

I have this code:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}" begin="${begin}" end="${end}" varStatus="loopStatus" step="1">
    <div class="home_app "${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? '' : 'white_bg'}">
```

When I browse to the jsp I am getting this in the div:

```
<div }="" white_bg="" :="" ?="" 0="" 2="=" %="" ${loopstatus.index="" class="home_app ">
```

Comment: What servletcontainer? What servlet version in web.xml? What if you use `c:out` on it instead?

Comment: Unfortunately this is Tomcat 4.1 after some searching I have found the ? operator is not supported in this old cruddy version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (change in bold):

```
<c:forEach var="product"
           items="${products}"
           begin="${begin}"
           end="${end}"
           varStatus="loopStatus"
           step="1">
    <div class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? '' : 'white_bg'}">
```

My personal preference is the following instead of the ?: operator:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${(loopStatus.index % 2) == 1}">
        <div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div class="white_bg">
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"` before the dollar sign seems to be at the wrong place. Remove it.

Comment: Is the output still the same?

Comment: It's not relevant for EL so no, this won't help anything.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator (and EL in template text) was introduced in JSP 2.0. Chances are that you're running a servletconainer which doesn't support JSP 2.0 or is declaring `web.xml` as Servlet 2.2 or older.